# angular 2 tree component click event

Tags: angular, typescript, treeview

In my angular2 project i have implemented angular tree component.i am using the following json data

```
nodes = [
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'root1',
  isExpanded: true,
  children: [
    { id: 2, name: 'child1' },
    { id: 3, name: 'child2' }
  ]
},
{
  id: 4,
  name: 'root2',
  children: [
    { id: 5, name: 'child2.1' },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: 'child2.2',
      children: [
        { id: 7, name: 'subsub' }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
];
```

And my html template is,

```
<tree-root [nodes]="nodes"></tree-root>

getNodeName()
{
//display selected node name
 console.log();
}
```

Tree displaying in my tree,but my problem is, how can i get clicked node details. i want to print selected node name inside the getNodeName() function.

Comment: What are clicked node details? Where do you want to get the from? What have you tried? What is the problem?

Comment: node details are id and name. For example, when i click on root2 node i want to get id:4 and name: root2.

Comment: Please provide more code. Where do you want to get the details?

Comment: click on what node?

Comment: i need root and children nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle event on each node of tree and fire it.
On `<tree root>` component:
`@Output() clickNode = new EventEmitter<Node>(); // with Node is class of data for node.`

in template:
`...`
`<your-tree-item (click)="clickHandler(node)"></your-tree-item>`
`...`
`clickHandler(node: Node){`
`this.clickNode.emit(node)`
`}`

Using your tree:
`<tree-root (clickNode)="yourHandler($event)"></tree-root>`

`yourHandler(node: Node) { alert(node.id) }`

I also writing a virtual tree component for angular 2+. And it also support your case. You can find at: https://github.com/NamNgKh/angular2_virtual_tree

I going to make CSS theme for it. so other can easily change style of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use "angular-tree-component", this will get the name of your node. Then you could improve it:

in your `.html`:

```
<tree-root [nodes]="nodes" [options]="options" (click)="clickHandler($event)"></tree-root>
```

in your `.ts`:

```
clickHandler(event: any) {
    if (event && event.target && event.target.childNodes[0]) {
        console.log(event.target.childNodes[0].data)
    }
}
```